# How to save a SELECT statement as a shell variable and INSERT it

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

How would I do the following:

```
$ VAR=`mysql -u root files -e 'select * from path'` # save SELECT as local var
$ mysql -u root files -e 'insert into path values `echo $VAR`' # INSERT var
```

The second command here doesn't work. What would be the correct syntax / way to do this?

Comment: The SQL syntax won't be correct as written after fixing the shell script syntax. Do you need help with that, too?

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Yes, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes to allow for variable interpolation. And `` `echo $VAR` `` is equivalent to plain `$VAR`.

```
mysql -u root files -e "insert into path values $VAR"
```

This won't fix the SQL syntax errors though. What are you trying to do, backup the `path` table? If so, the [mysqldump command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is the [tool to use](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works in that it interpolates the values, but the way I'm doing it gives a sql error (in that the VAR from the SELECT statement isn't saved in a valid way for the INSERT statement). How would I get around doing this?